Every request sent with fetch() has a different sessionId cookie, which prevents me from tracking the session across requests
I have a react front-end application running on localhost:3000, and a Django backend server running on 127.0.0.1:8000
I am sending the request from a function using fetch()
Using both widthCredentials and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is probably overkill but I am trying anything at this point.
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
                'withCredentials': 'true',
 
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })

In my Django backend I have installed django-cors-headers and set all settings correctly AFAIK.
Djang is not complaining about any requests so I believe my Django setup is correct.
For some reason the sessionId cookie in every request is different so I can't use it to track a session across requests. Instead Django creates a new session for each request.
Django settings
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    ...
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = False
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    "accept",
    "accept-encoding",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "dnt",
    "origin",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",
    "cache-control",
    "pragma",
    "access-control-allow-credentials",
    "withCredentials",
]


# use file to store sessions
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.file'
SESSION_FILE_PATH = "/path/to/dir"

SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "localhost"
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True  # if this is to TRUE cookies dont work propoerly, not sure why
# SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'


print() the HttpRequest.headers to know if the client sends the 'sessionid'. If it doesn’t, that is your culprit.

withCredentials is not a header, and you cant set CORS headers client side.

@Evert this still doesn’t explain why the header doesn’t have the "sessionid".

@ChukwujiobiCanon You're right, the sessionId was not being inluded in the request. I don't know why but now all of a sudden it is. A user below suggested the SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN is incorrect (should be None or "127.0.0.1") so I changed that and now everything works but I don't understand why that would cause the sessionId to be included all of a sudden. To be honest I'm not sure why it works all of a sudden

"127.0.0.1" and "localhost" are not the same. Even though they route to the same host on a network, they are different domains and browsers treat them differently.

I don't really understand what SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN does. Does it specify on which domains the cookie is valid? How is the browser informed of this? When I inspect the server response I see a Set-Cookie header with the id but I don't see any field that includes this cookie domain

Exactly. The server communicates that via response headers then the browser takes it up from there.

@ChukwujiobiCanon That explains it! Thanks for your help
